# How to check for Forward Slash within this Regex for all special characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find a regex solution to check if a string matches all conditions + `/` forward slashes.

Current code:

`var specialChars = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g;`

This will match true if a string looks like so: `4!@#$`.

However it does not work if the string looks like this: `5/6/2019`

---

This is how I'm implementing this check, basically I have a function that takes in an long string. And what I'm trying to do is pluck out the tracking ID then create a link out of it.

My test cases are also in the demo, the date test is the one that fails, since the linkCreator function ends up linking to the date:

https://jsfiddle.net/cojuevp5/

```js
var linkCreator = function(value) {
  var strings = value.split(' ');
  var aHref = '<a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=';
  var targetBlank = '" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline">';

  var trackingString = strings.reduce(function(prevVal, currVal, idx) {
    var specialChars = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g;
    // Does val start with number and not contain special characters including /
    var link = currVal.match(/^\d/) && !currVal.match(specialChars) ?
      aHref + currVal + targetBlank + currVal + '</a>' :
      currVal;
    return idx == 0 ? link : prevVal + ' ' + link;
  }, '');

  console.log(trackingString);
}

const case1 = '434663008870'
const case2 = '4S4663008870'
const case3 = '4S4663008870 PS'
const case4 = 'SHD FX 462367757727 PS'
const case5 = 'SHD FX 429970755485, R'
const case6 = 'SHD HEADER TRACKING PS'
const case7 = 'N/A'
const case8 = 'AF SHD FX 462367757727 PS'
const case9 = '4/7/2019'
const case10 = '4!@#$%^&'

const value = case9

const link = linkCreator(value)
console.log(link)
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `$`, `&`, `)`, and `(` inside `[]`. You only need to escape `^` if it's at the beginning.

Comment: @Barmar oh do you mean in the check for `specialChars`? Or my test `case10`?

Comment: In `specialChars`. You're not escaping anything in `case10`, so why would I tell you not to?

Comment: @Barmar so you mean change \$%\^\&*\ to \^\? I just tried that and it failed my test10 and created a link around `4!@#$%^&`.

Comment: Change `\$%\^\&*\)\(` to `$%^&*)(`

Comment: Hmm this still does not work for my function, it no longer links the wrong items, but it does not link the ids anymore either. This is what is working: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\/\(+=._-]+$/g`

Comment: The answer you accepted removed all the unnecessary backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add a `\/` and that would likely solve your problem:

```
^([A-z0-9!\/@#$%^&*)(+=._-]+)$
```

Just like [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) says, you do not need to escape all chars inside `[]`:

I'm guessing that this may be what you might want to match:

[image]

You might just use [this tool](https://regex101.com/r/OOnvxo/1) and design any expression that you wish.

#### Graph

This graph shows how your expression works:

[image]

Comment: Ah thanks! That helped point me to where I needed to look, but this is the actual syntax that worked: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\/\(+=._-]+$/g` needed to add \/\ between the `)` and `(`

Comment: I also just discovered this nice and short goodie :) `var specialChars = /\W|_/g; `